# how to display generated images in jsp page?

Tags: java, html, jsp, qr-code

```
<%@page import="com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>

    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <%@page language='java'%>
    <%@page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.util.Hashtable,javax.imageio.*,com.google.zxing.*,com.google.zxing.client.*,com.google.zxing.common.*,com.google.zxing.qrcode.decoder.*"%>
     <% 
    String qrCodeData = "Hello World!";
    String filePath = "QRCode.png";
    String charset = "UTF-8"; // or "ISO-8859-1"
    Hashtable hintMap = new Hashtable();
    hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);

    createQRCode(qrCodeData, filePath, charset, hintMap, 200, 200);
    out.println("QR Code image created successfully!");

%>      
<%!

public void createQRCode(String qrCodeData, String filePath,
        String charset,Hashtable hintMap, int qrCodeheight, int qrCodewidth)
        throws WriterException, IOException {
    BitMatrix matrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(
            new String(qrCodeData.getBytes(charset), charset),
            BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, qrCodewidth, qrCodeheight,hintMap);
    MatrixToImageWriter.writeToFile(matrix, filePath.substring(filePath
            .lastIndexOf('.') + 1), new File(filePath));
}




        %>

</body>
</html>
```

This code generates QR image in tomcat\bin directory.I want to change the directory to location where jsp files present.So that I could display them in webpage
Pls help...

Answer (score 0):

I made an example that generate qrcode without saving it. See this answer:
[Display dynamically generated image to the browser using jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332603/display-dynamically-generated-image-to-the-browser-using-jsp/51142396#51142396)